# Sending more than one string in socket programming python

Tags: python, sockets, raspberry-pi, gpio

I want to send data more than once. I have the following code on server and client:

On server :

```
import socket
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(14,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(15,GPIO.OUT)

serversocket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host="10.168.1.50"
port=80
print(host)
print(port)
serversocket.bind((host,port))


serversocket.listen(5)
print('server started listening')
while 1:
    (clientsocket,address)=serversocket.accept()
    print("connection established from : ",address)
    data=clientsocket.recv(1024).decode()
    print(data)
    if (data=='hai'):
        GPIO.output(14,True)
        GPIO.output(15,False)
        print 'hello'
    else:
        GPIO.output(14,False)
        GPIO.output(15,False)
    clientsocket.send("data is sent".encode())
```

On client:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = "10.168.1.50"
port = 80
s.connect((host,port))
while True:

    in_data=raw_input(" Enter data to be sent > ")
    s.send(in_data.encode())
    s.send('hai'.encode())
    data = ''
    data = s.recv(1024).decode()
    print (data)
    s.close
```

I send the first string, get the response, but when I send the second string, it hangs.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Look at your client code.  Second time round the loop, what is different about the socket 's'?  Yes- you've closed it:)

Comment: Beware you write `s.close` here but i guess on your side you intend `s.close()` and that's your problem...you're closing the connection after the first send.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that worked

On server :

```
import socket
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(14,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(15,GPIO.OUT)

serversocket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host="10.168.1.50"
port=80
print(host)
print(port)
serversocket.bind((host,port))


serversocket.listen(5)
print('server started listening')
(clientsocket,address)=serversocket.accept()
print("connection established from : ",address)
while 1:
    data=clientsocket.recv(1024).decode()
    print(data)
    if (data=='hai'):
        GPIO.output(14,True)
        GPIO.output(15,False)
        print 'hello'
    else:
        GPIO.output(14,False)
        GPIO.output(15,False)
    clientsocket.send("data is sent".encode())
```

On client:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = "10.168.1.50"
port = 80
s.connect((host,port))
try:
    while True:

        in_data=raw_input(" Enter data to be sent > ")
        s.send(in_data.encode())
        data = ''
        data = s.recv(1024).decode()
        print (data)
finally:
    s.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

This my client and it's working.

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = "10.168.1.50"
port = 80
s.connect((host,port))
try:
    while True:
        in_data=raw_input(" Enter data to be sent > ")
        s.send(in_data.encode())
        s.send('hai'.encode())
        data = ''
        data = s.recv(1024).decode()
        print (data)
finally:
    s.close()
```

Comment: Sorry that alone didn't solve my problem. Modification was needed on  the server side too. :) Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I had to move 
       (clientsocket,address)=serversocket.accept()
above the while. Then it worked :)